# How do I prove that the ODE satisfies ？

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve this ODE
$$
\frac{\sin \theta}{\Theta(\theta)} \frac{d}{d \theta}\left(\sin \theta \frac{d \Theta}{d \theta}\right)+\beta \sin ^2 \theta=m^2
$$
where $\beta=\frac{2 I E}{\hbar^2}$

Why should the following condition be satisfied ?

$$
\beta=J(J+1) \quad J=0,1,2, \ldots
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{\sin \theta}{\Theta(\theta)} \frac{d}{d \theta}\left(\sin \theta \frac{d \Theta}{d \theta}\right)+\beta \sin ^2 \theta=m^2
$$
In interest of simpler editing let $\Theta=y$ and $\theta=x$.

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{y(x)} \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin(x) \frac{dy}{dx}\right)+\beta \sin^2(x)=m^2 \tag 1$$

$$\sin^2(x)\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+\sin(x)\cos(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+\left(\beta\sin^2(x)-m^2\right)y(x)=0 \tag 2$$
Change of variable :
$$t=\cos(x)\quad\implies\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=-\sin(x)\frac{dy}{dt} \quad\implies\quad \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=\sin^2(x)\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}-\cos(x)\frac{dy}{dt}$$
Putting them into Eq.$(2)$ and after simplification :
$$(1-t^2)^2\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}-2t\frac{dy}{dt}+\left(\beta(1-t^2)-m^2\right)y=0$$
This is the associated Legendre differential equation :
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendreDifferentialEquation.html where $\beta=J(J+1)$.
The general solution is :
$$y(t)=c_1P^m_J(t)+c_2Q^m_J(t)$$
$P^m_J$ and $Q^m_J$ are the associated Legendre functions of first and second kind respectively. Or associated Legendre polynomial if $J$ is an integer.

The solution of ODE $(1)$ is :
$$y(x)=c_1P^m_J\left(\cos(x)\right)+c_2Q^m_J\left(\cos(x)\right) \quad\text{with}\quad J(J+1)=\beta$$

On purely mathematical viewpoint there is no need for $J$ to be an integer.

If a polynomial is needed, then $J$ has to be an integer. One cannot say more without knowing the context and if they are some physical reason to which a polynomial is wanted instead of a function ( i.e. a function equivalent to infinite series instead of finite power series).

In the present case the functions $P^m_J$ and $Q^m_J$ are involved. They are well documented special functions.

Note about the PRACTICAL USE OF SPECIAL FUNCTIONS :

Citation from https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales pp. 22-23.

We see the considerable advantage which comes from using standard special functions. This avoids to taking back the whole problem for every met case and moreover, this allows to express the result with functions which each one can recognize and can find in handbooks and in software...

... "standard" or "typical" species are duly listed, described. They were dissected, analyzed. Their properties were deeply studied. A large number of relationships between them are established, recorded. There are tables, algorithms for each of them. In brief, in a nutshell, an immense background is available. But to reach it, a key is needed, more exactly a keyword : it is necessary to know the name of the appropriate special function...

... Nowadays, the art of the Mathematician in this domain is relieved by software for formal calculation. Certainly, it does not replace the indispensable skill. Nevertheless, in many circumstances, integral calculus, differential equations, etc. the software *** will be able to bring out a formula, sometimes esoteric at first sight and including special functions. In doing it, he does not give the Solution (with a big S), but he gives an important piece of information: the name of the relevant special functions and how they act. Then, it is up to the user to decide if this closed form is enough for him, because the special functions are familiar objects for him. If not, it is up to the user to search in the books what are the properties of the special function and to find the information which are lacking to him, or to find the intermediate developments which the use of a special function has "short-circuited".

End of citation.